# need to execute a patricular set of statements in while loop

Tags: python-3.x

In the following code if i enter index value as string i want the program to ask for index value again instead of asking list values again. i need to do it with single set of try block

```
verify = True
while verify:
    try:
        li_a = []
        x = int(input("Please give the range for li_a : "))

        for num in range(0, x):
            number = int(input("Please enter the numbers for List li_a : "))
            li_a.append(number)

        index_place = int(input("please enter index value : "))
        store_value = li_a[index_place]
        print("\nThe value in List[li_a] corresponding to index number is : ", store_value)

        break

    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter an Integer value")
    except IndexError:
        print("The entered index value is not correct")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need an exception-handling

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    verify = True
    while verify:
        li_a = []


        def get_range():
            return input("Please give the range for li_a : ")


        x = get_range()
        while not x.isnumeric():
            print('Please enter a integer value')
            x = get_range()
        for num in range(0, int(x)):
            number = int(input("Please enter the numbers for List li_a : "))
            li_a.append(number)


        def get_index():
            return input("please enter index value : ")


        index_place = get_index()
        while not index_place.isnumeric() or len(li_a) <= int(index_place):
            index_place = get_index()
        store_value = li_a[int(index_place)]
        print("\nThe value in List[li_a] corresponding to index number is : ", store_value)

output = """
Please give the range for li_a : 2
Please enter the numbers for List li_a : 9
Please enter the numbers for List li_a : 8
please enter index value : 0

The value in List[li_a] corresponding to index number is :  9
Please give the range for li_a : 2
Please enter the numbers for List li_a : 9
Please enter the numbers for List li_a : 8
please enter index value : 1

The value in List[li_a] corresponding to index number is :  8
Please give the range for li_a : a
Please enter a integer value
"""
```